# Convert Rainbow gradient Shader to 3 colors gradient

Tags: unity, shaders

I am attempting to convert this rainbow shader into just using three colors.
I thought I would be able to set the three colors in the shader file, but I can't understand how to link them through the shader helper file.

```
shader: https://hastebin.com/uworiduluc.cs
Shader helper: https://hastebin.com/kifezufegi.cs

fixed4 frag(fragmentInput i) : SV_TARGET
{
    fixed2 lPos = i.localPosition / _Spread;
    half time = _Time.y * _Speed / _Spread;
    half timeWithOffset = time + _TimeOffset;
    fixed sine = sin(timeWithOffset);
    fixed cosine = cos(timeWithOffset);

    fixed hue = (-lPos.y) / 2.0;
    hue += time;

    while (hue < 0.0) hue += 1.0;
        while (hue > 1.0) hue -= 1.0;
            fixed4 hsl = fixed4(hue, _Saturation, _Luminosity, 1.0);

    return HSLtoRGB(hsl);
}
```

I added these properties at the top

```
_Color3 ("Top", Color) = (1,1,0,1)    
_Color2 ("Middle", Color) = (1,1,0,1)
_Color1 ("Bottom", Color) = (1,1,0,1)
```

But I am not sure where I can add them into the code to have them be the colors that are used.

Comment: Please assume every link will not be clicked, or will not work (sooner or later, everything rots). Embed a minimal complete verifiable example of the code you need help with in your question itself. This will help you get answers significantly faster.

Comment: Hue is the varying parameter that causes the rainbow effect. It ranges from [0,1] inclusive, so you could consider it to represent the endpoints of your gradient. Have you tried linear interpolation between your colors i.e. Color1-Color2 in the range hue=[0,0.5] and Color2-Color3 in the range hue=[0.5,1.0]?